# How to update vertices geometry after rotate or move object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can use position & rotation values to transform a mesh.

Ok, I see how the changes looks right but I'd want a way to transform the geometry vertices x,y,z, freeing and/or reseting the rotation & position values.
I dont't know how to do it....

I have played with :

```
myobj.applymatrix();
myobj.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
myobj.verticesNeedUpdate;
```

instead of setting position & rotation, but the result is the same: Yes, the changes are right but the internal geometry did not change.

Have I to apply the geometric transform to vertices manually ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try `mesh.updateMatrix(); mesh.geometry.applyMatrix( mesh.matrix ); mesh.matrix.identity();` Also reset `position`, `rotation`, and `scale` to their initial values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to transform the vertices of your geometry, use this pattern:

```
mesh.updateMatrix(); 
mesh.geometry.applyMatrix( mesh.matrix );
mesh.matrix.identity();
```

Then reset the `position`, `rotation`, and `scale` properties to their initial values:

```
mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
mesh.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0 );
mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
```

three.js r.85

Answer (score 0):

While building a ground mesh using a PlaneGeometry, adding hills using a heightmap and then getting some random vertices from the mesh geometry and adding trees **after** rotating the ground using

```
ground_mesh.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
```

the mesh.geometry vertices aren't rotated along with the mesh and my trees are placed in pre-mesh-rotation positions.  **I found a quick and easy solution** by instead rotating the mesh using

```
ground_mesh.geometry.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2)
```

and everything, including my gravity collision detection, and the random vertices all provide the expected results.

The [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry.rotateX) mentions that *rotateX* shouldn't be used during the rendering loop.