# Three.js - Get rotated vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to get the new positions of an object's vertices after rotating it using `Object.rotation.x`. Unfortunately the vertices stay the same and only the rotation matrix is updated. Is there a way to directly get the new points without calculating it all by yourself?

Comment: I've never worked with three.js, but doing it yourself is not that hard. Loop over all vertices, transform them with the rotation matrix, store them in a new array. Is it difficult to create a new three.js Object to store the data in?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be a big issue. I just wondered if there is a way to get the rotated values directly, which would be handy. But thanks :)

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990354/how-to-update-vertices-geometry-after-rotate-or-move-object

Comment: Thanks, this is how I currently do it. Guess this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var geom = Object3D.geometry.clone();
geom.applyMatrix(Object3D.matrix);
geom.vertices[n] -  value you need;
```

or

```
var vec = Object3D.geometry.vertices[n].clone();
vec.applyMatrix4(Object3D.matrix);
```

Comment: An answer solely consisting of code with no or little explanation makes it difficult to understand which approach the asker should take and why your answer is viable. Please add explanations to your code.

Comment: Thanks, but this is also the approach that I currently take. I was looking for a different method since copying all the data isn't that efficient.. But I guess that's how it works.