# three.js applyMatrix after scale results in error

Tags: javascript, three.js

**The problem:**
I am looking to update the vertice positions on a mesh after scaling. I am doing this because I need to calculate the volume of the mesh. I am creating a cloned mesh to do this because I need to keep scale an active parameter in the origin mesh.

I was using the answer at [How to update vertices geometry after rotate or move object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990354/how-to-update-vertices-geometry-after-rotate-or-move-object)

Which worked fine with three.js release .70, but has broken on release .72

**My code:**

```
  var volumeClone =  new THREE.Mesh (this.mesh.geometry.clone(), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ));
  volumeClone.scale.z = heightScale;
  volumeClone.updateMatrix();
  volumeClone.geometry.applyMatrix( volumeClone.matrix );
  volumeClone.matrix.identity();
  volumeClone.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  volumeClone.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
  console(calculateVolume(volumeClone));
```

**Result:**

In Chrome is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFromPoints' of undefined
THREE.Geometry.computeBoundingBox 
@lib.min.js:3THREE.Geometry.applyMatrix

**What I have tried:**
I have attempted to investigate and isolate the issue within Geometry.js and Box3.js as well as understand the programmatic flow to understand why "this.boundBox" is undefined, but I haven't found the issue.

**Question:**
Is the syntax correct? Was there an update to three.js in this area?

Comment: Use three.js, not three.min.js, for development. Use the current version of three.js. Try to track down the issue. Post a jsfiddle if you have problems.

Comment: Ok I did that. I tracked the issue further down to this.mesh.geometry.clone() which seems to only copy faceVertexUvs, faces,vertices and the prototype. It does not copy the geometry object default properties as listed in Geometry.js? There is no name, type, id, etc. so boundingBox is undefined, which causes the visible error in Geometry.applyMatrix. Is there a different clone method I should be using?

Comment: @WestLangley The clone is of type extrudeGeometry by the way. I am not sure if this is part of the issue.

Comment: Can you fork [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/) and provide a _simple_ live example that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Wes, thank you kindly for all your hard work with three.js community and providing the default fiddle which came in handy! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that extrudeGeometry does not contain the same properties as regular geometry and so doing work on it doesn't work since particulars are missing. The answer is to convert bufferGeometry to regular geometry before trying to work with it as regular geometry. I understand the performance benefits of using buffers, but in this case I can create a geometry for measurements and trash it when I get a result.

So rather than "clone" geometry as shown in my question, I switch to creating the particular type Geometry from the buffer instance:

```
  var volumeClone =  new THREE.Mesh (new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( this.mesh.geometry._bufferGeometry ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ));
  volumeClone.scale.z = heightScale;
  volumeClone.updateMatrix();
  volumeClone.geometry.applyMatrix( volumeClone.matrix );
  volumeClone.matrix.identity();
  volumeClone.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  volumeClone.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
  console(calculateVolume(volumeClone));
```

This has the added benefit of working with any geometry type I have thrown at it thus far: extrusions, imported mesh, primitives...