# Raycasting against a mesh is not found where it 's visible in the scene

Tags: three.js

I'm having a strange problem with raycasting. My scene consists of a room with a couple of components that you can move around inside that room. When the component is moving i'm measuring the distances to the walls, an invisible roof and floor. The problem is that the roof which is a ShapeGeometry is visible where it should be at the top of the walls but not hit when raycasting.

Here's where i create the mesh for the invisible roof

```
const roofShape = new THREE.Shape();
roofShape.moveTo(roofPoints[0].x, roofPoints[0].y);
for (let i = 1; i < roofPoints.length; i++) {
    roofShape.lineTo(roofPoints[i].x, roofPoints[i].y);
}
roofShape.lineTo(roofPoints[0].x, roofPoints[0].y);

const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(roofShape);

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
material.opacity = 0;
material.transparent = true;
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.x = 0;
mesh.position.y = 0;
mesh.position.z = room._height;
mesh.name = "ROOF";
mesh.userData = <Object3DUserData> {
    id: IntersectType.INVISIBLE_ROOF,
    intersectType: IntersectType.INVISIBLE_ROOF,
};
```

The function that's invoking the raycasting. The direction vector is(0, 0, 1) in this case. And the surfaces parameter is an array which only contains the mesh created above.

```
function getDistanceToSurface(componentPosition: THREE.Vector3, surfaces: THREE.Object3D[], direction: THREE.Vector3): number {
    const rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster(componentPosition, direction.normalize());
    const intersections = rayCaster.intersectObjects(surfaces);

    if (!intersections || !intersections.length) {
        return 0;
    }

    const val = intersections[0].distance;

    return val;
}
```

By changing the z direction to -1 i found that the raycaster found the roof at z=0. It seems that the geometry is still at position z=0.

I then tried to translate the geometry shape

```
geometry.translate(0, 0, room._height);
```

And now the raycaster finds it where i expect it to be. But visually it it's double the z position(mesh opacity=1). Setting the mesh position z to 0 makes it visibly correct and the raycasting still works.

I've been looking at the examples of raycasting but can't find anywhere where a ShapeGeometry needs do this.

Am i doing something wrong? Have i missed something? Do i have to set z position of the geometry, is it not enough with positioning the mesh?

Comment: Try to update the geometry so it is literally in the new position that the mesh has been translated to. The raycaster looks at geometry and bufferGeometry only. Luckily there are methods ready to make this simple. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990354/how-to-update-vertices-geometry-after-rotate-or-move-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159931/raycasting-against-a-mesh-is-not-found-where-it-s-visible-in-the-scene?noredirect=1#comment65686477_39159931) by @radio the solution was as described in [How to update vertices geometry after rotate or move object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990354/how-to-update-vertices-geometry-after-rotate-or-move-object)

```
mesh.position.z = room._height;
mesh.updateMatrix();
mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(mesh.matrix);
mesh.matrix.identity();
```