# THREE JS: Get updated position of a rotated point

Tags: javascript, three.js

I render some points in THREE JS and rotate them. I want to get the updated position of a point with a specific index. How do I do that?

Here is a CodePen for demonstration:
https://codepen.io/joshua-holly-fraunhofer/pen/VwyGBVO
(Notice commented lines 64 and 65).

```
function render() {
  points.rotation.x += 0.01;
  points.rotation.y += 0.02;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
  // console.log(points[34].position.x);
  // console.log(points[34].position.y);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update vertices geometry after rotate or move object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990354/how-to-update-vertices-geometry-after-rotate-or-move-object)

Comment: Not really, since they are using Mesh and Setters. For me its Points and Getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, thanks to answer from Deep. When I set the rotation values directly (see question), the position values in the geometry stay the same. But when I rotate the geometry, the position values within update:

```
    points.geometry.rotateX(0.01);
    points.geometry.rotateY(0.02);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
    const positionArray = points.geometry.attributes.position.array;
    const [x, y, z] = [positionArray[34*3], positionArray[34*3 + 1], positionArray[34*3 + 2]];
    console.log(x, y, z);
```

Although documentation says not to use the rotate function inside a loop: https://threejs.org/docs/?q=geom#api/en/core/BufferGeometry

Answer (score 0):

Position is a Float32 BufferAttribute of the geometry with size 3 corresponding to x, y, z of each vertex: https://threejs.org/docs/?q=geom#api/en/core/BufferGeometry

```
const positionArray = points.geometry.attributes.position.array;
const [x, y, z] = [positionArray[34*3], positionArray[34*3 + 1], positionArray[34*2]];
console.log(x, y, z);
```

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks. For this to work, I have to rotate the geometry instead of the points (see my answer).